# The Error is coming mgr is field but used like type

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace OOPSProject
{
    class HeadOffice
    {
        string mgr;
        mgr = "Mr.Amol Pawal";
        public void HeadOfficeAddress()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pune");
        }
        public void HeadOfficeManager()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Manager is:" + mgr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually asked the question...

Comment: @Amol Pawal did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a value to a variable (`mgr` in your case) out of class methods. Put `mgr = "Mr.Amol Pawal";` in your constructor or use `string mgr = "Mr.Amol Pawal";`.

Answer (score 1):

**mgr** is a field it must be assigned with aconstructor or with declaration

1st way:in constructor

```
class HeadOffice
{
    public HeadOffice()
    {
        mgr = "Mr.Amol Pawal";
    }
    string mgr;
    public void HeadOfficeAddress()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pune");
    }
    public void HeadOfficeManager()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Manager is:" + mgr);
    }
}
```

2nd way:with declaration

```
class HeadOffice
{
    string mgr= "Mr.Amol Pawal";;
    public void HeadOfficeAddress()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pune");
    }
    public void HeadOfficeManager()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Manager is:" + mgr);
    }
}
```

if you don't know the difference between field and variable

see:[What is the difference between field, variable, attribute, and property in Java POJOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115588/what-is-the-difference-between-field-variable-attribute-and-property-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
string mgr = "Mr. Amol Pawal";
```

Comment: Please extend your answer, why this is the solution.