# How to use a variable from a get method in an another method?

Tags: java, methods, scope

Below I have included the code I was working on.

I need to create a class that takes 3 points, and can return the side length, and angles of those points.

I am having trouble at my `computeAngles`  method. I am trying to call three methods there to `getSide1_Length` and side2 and 3 lengths. But I am having a little trouble.

It is not finished. I still need to get angle1, and angle3, but I want to figure out angle 2 before I continue.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Triangle
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private Point p1, p2, p3;
    private double angle1,angle2,angle3;

    public Triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        p1 = p1;
        p2 = p2;
        p3 = p3;
    }

    public Point setPoint1(Point p1)
    {
        this.p1 = new Point();
        return p1;
    }

    public Point setPoint2(Point p2)
    {
        this.p2 = new Point();
        return p2;
    }

    public Point setPoint3(Point p3)
    {
        this.p3 = new Point();
        return p3;
    }

    public Point getPoint1()
    {
        return p1;
    }

    public Point getPoint2()
    {
        return p2;
    }

    public Point getPoint3()
    {
        return p3;
    }

    public double getSide1_Length(double side1)
    {
        side1 = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2)) + Math.pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2)));

        return side1;
    }

    public double getSide2_Length(double side2)
    {
        side2 = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow((p3.x - p2.x), 2)) + Math.pow((p3.y - p2.y), 2)));

        return side2;
    }

    public double getSide3_Length(double side3)
    {
        side3 = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow((p3.x - p1.x),2)) + Math.pow((p3.y - p1.y),2)));

        return side3;
    }

    public double getAngle1()
    {
        return angle1;
    }

    public double getAngle2()
    {
        return angle2;
    }

    public double getAngle3()
    {
        return angle3;
    }

    private double computeAngles(double angle1, double angle2, double angle3)
    {
        double side1 = getSide1_Length(side1);
        double side2 = getSide2_Length(side2);
        double side3 = getSide3_Length(side3);

        angle2 = Math.asin(((Math.pow(side3,2)) - (Math.pow(side2,2)) - (Math.pow(side1,2)) / (-2 * (side2 * side1))));

        return angle2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should rework your **constructor**.

```
p1 = p1;
```

I think what you want to do is setting your fields to the parameters of your constructor. What you do there is putting the parameter into the parameter. 
Now there are 2 common solutions to that problem. Eighter you rename your parameter or place a "this." in front of the left p1.

```
this.p1 = p1; // this.p1 is the field | p1 is the parameter
```

Your **setPoint()** methods need some work too. What you want to do is set your field to the value of the parameter. You're creating new Objects each time.

```
this.p1 = p1; // this.p1 is the field | p1 is the parameter
```

Your **getSide()** methods shouldn't take any parameters since they are just returning the side's lenght based on the points you store in your fields. So change them to something like:

```
public double getSide1_Length()
{
    double side1 = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2)) + Math.pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2)));

    return side1;
}
```

For your **computeAngle()** method take a look here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html

Based on that link you should do the following:

```
private double computeAngles()
{
    double side1 = getSide1_Length(side1);
    double side2 = getSide2_Length(side2);
    double side3 = getSide3_Length(side3);

    int angle2 = Math.acos(((Math.pow(side3,2)) + (Math.pow(side2,2)) - (Math.pow(side1,2)) / (2 * (side3 * side2))));

    return angle2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change things a little bit.

`getSide1`, `getSide2` and `getSide3`: all of them do the same thing, the only difference is the points used in the calculation. So you should change them to have **one single** method that receives 2 points and do the math:

```
public double getSideLength(Point a, Point b)
{
    return Math.sqrt(((Math.pow((a.x - b.x),2)) + Math.pow((a.y - b.y),2)));
}
```

Then, to compute the angles, note that when you do:

```
private double computeAngles(double angle1, double angle2, double angle3)
```

Those `angle` variables are **not** the same as the ones declared at the beginning (the ones with the `private` modifier) - [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115588/what-is-the-difference-between-field-variable-attribute-and-property-in-java) for details.

To correctly compute the angles, you call `getSideLength` 3 times to get the lengths of the 3 sides, and then do the respective calculations with the sides:

```
private void computeAngles() {
    double side1 = getSideLength(p1, p2);
    double side2 = getSideLength(p2, p3);
    double side3 = getSideLength(p3, p1);

    angle2 = Math.asin(((Math.pow(side3,2)) - (Math.pow(side2,2)) - (Math.pow(side1,2)) / (-2 * (side2 * side1))));
    angle1 = // do the same math using the respective sides
    angle3 = // do the same math using the respective sides
}
```

As the math to get the angle is the same (only the sides used change), you could also create a method for that:

```
private double getAngle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
    return Math.asin(((Math.pow(sideC, 2)) - (Math.pow(sideB, 2)) - (Math.pow(sideA, 2)) / (-2 * (sideB * sideA))));
}
```

Then you compute the angles like that:

```
private void computeAngles() {
    double side1 = getSideLength(p1, p2);
    double side2 = getSideLength(p2, p3);
    double side3 = getSideLength(p3, p1);

    angle1 = getAngle(side1, side2, side3);
    angle2 = // call getAngle changing the sides order accordingly
    angle3 = // call getAngle changing the sides order accordingly
}
```