# Why we can't declare variables in class constructor in java?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

If constructors are implicitly invoked functions at the time of object creation then we should declare variable in constructor , but it is giving an error.

```
class A{
    
    public A(){
        int a =5;
    }
}


public class assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A obj = new A();
       System.out.println(obj.a);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        a cannot be resolved or is not a field

        at ass2.main(ass2.java:14)
```

Comment: Of course you can. It just exists only within that constructor, not outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `int a` is not a field but, as you said, variable and immediately after the constructor will finish it's not accessible anymore and definitely not by `obj.a`

You should move it's definition outside the constructor (so basically create **field** `a`) if you wish to use it this way

[What is the difference between field, variable, attribute, and property in Java POJOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115588/what-is-the-difference-between-field-variable-attribute-and-property-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
    public int a;

    public A(){
        this.a =5;
    }
}
```

For more information on declaring constructors refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

It'a just a member variables, which doesn't belong to obj, u should declare a as local variables:

```java
public class Test{
    public int a = 5;
    public Test() {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variables in constructor `int a` (in your case) will still work locally in the constructor. the `a` variable will be destroyed as the constructor finish his work. so you can't access to this Variable from another place.

To create a field and make your code work. take the declaration outside of the constructor. then you can initialize it in the constructor..