# In Objective-C with ARC, is it true that we usually only need to specify nonatomic as property attributes?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

It is strange that in Big Nerd Ranch iOS 5 book (p.73) and Programming iOS 5 book (O'Reilly, p.314) **(updadte: even Kochan's Objective-C book Fourth edition)**, in the context of ARC, they say the default for properties attribute is `assign`... But [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) says the default is `strong`.

I also tried a simple program where if I don't specify `strong`, the program works ok, and if I specify `strong`, it works the same, and when `assign` is used instead, the compiler shows a warning, so it seems the default is indeed `strong`.

So if most of the time, we want

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSMutableArray *foo;
```

then we can just write

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *foo;
```

as the other two (`readwrite` and `strong`) are the default?

Comment: Assign is only used with none ARC which is why you get the compiler warning.

Comment: but the warning is not about using `assign` in ARC.  It is about the object will be released sooner than usually expected

Comment: `assign` is the same as `unsafe_unretained` under ARC. In other words, the behavior is the same as with assign under MRC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

readwrite and strong, are indeed the default under ARC*. Under manual reference counting, assign was (is) the default. I prefer to explicitly specify these, because it makes it clearer what the @property's parameters are instead of relying on the person reading the code knowing what the defaults are.

*strong is the default assuming you've either let the compiler synthesize an instance variable for you, or have declared an instance variable without an explicit ownership qualifier (in which case the ivar is `__strong` by default anyway). Otherwise, the default property ownership type matches the ownership qualifier in the ivar's declaration. So, if you explicitly declare an ivar with `__weak`, then declare an @property for it without an ownership qualifier, the synthesized property will be weak. This is all documented in the [Clang ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: that's true... if for other people to read the code... do you specify just `nonatomic, strong` then?

Comment: by the way... even Kochan's Objective-C book says the default is not `strong`... so maybe something changed recently...

Comment: As stated in my answer, strong is the default under ARC. assign is the default under manual memory management (i.e. non-ARC), so yes, the default effectively changed for new code when ARC was introduced. I _always_ explicitly specify the ownership when I declare properties.

Comment: Ahh, OK. In that case they're wrong. The documentation I linked to in my answer confirms that strong is the default under ARC.

Comment: You're right. It was in LLVM 3.1 to be precise, which explains the books' differing from the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

By default, an object property is `strong, atomic, readwrite`. See
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html