# Is typing strong in properties really necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dude;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *dude;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *dude;
```

What exactly is the difference between these 3?

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between the first and second, as "`strong`" is the [default & implicit attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827237/what-are-the-default-attributes-for-objective-c-properties).

The third uses a weak reference, which means that when the object is released by the last owner, the `dude` property becomes nil.

Oh, lastly, NSString properties should actually be declared with "`NSString *`".

Comment: And often with strings you should consider using `copy`.