# unowned vs. weak. Why we should prefer unowned?

Tags: swift, memory-management, retain-cycle

As Apple said in "The Swift Programming Language", it seems we should prefer `unowned` than `weak` whenever possible:

> If the captured reference will never become nil, it should always be captured as an unowned reference, rather than a weak reference.

From the "Weak and Unowned References" section on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

I did know the difference between these two. But I am curious about is there any good reason for preferring  `unowned` than `weak`? I think the `weak` is much safer and we can just always write `[weak obj]` and an optional binding check without thinking the possibility of existing of the `obj`.

Is it related to some performance consideration or something I missed? Or is it totally ok to use `weak` instead of `unowned` all the time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Weak references are automatically set to `nil` once the object they point to gets deallocated. For this to be possible in Swift, those must be declared as `var` and optional:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    weak var weakProperty: SomeClass?
}
```

This is fine if the `weakProperty` can become `nil` while the instance of `SomeOtherClass` is still alive and we want to check for that before using it (delegates are one such example). But what if some reference should never logically be `nil` and we still want to prevent a retain cycle? In Objective-C any object reference can be `nil` (and messaging `nil` always fails silently) so there is no dilemma, we always use `weak`. But Swift doesn't have nilable references at all. We use optionals for something that can semantically lack value. But we shouldn't be forced to use optionals for something that must always have value, just to be able to break a retain cycle. Such practice would go against the intended semantics of optionals.

That's where `unowned` comes in. It comes in two flavours - `unowned(safe)` and `unowned(unsafe)`. The latter is dangerous and it's equivalent to `assign` and `unsafe_unretained` from Objective-C. But the former, which is the default one (at least while debugging; not sure if they optimise it to `unowned(unsafe)` in release builds), will reliably crash your app if the referenced object gets prematurely deallocated. Sure, your app will crash if something goes wrong, but that's much easier to debug than failing silently. It should only fail silently when you actually want that (in which case you would use `weak`)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift strong, weak, unowned reference**

[[Objective-C property attributes]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282129/4770877)

`ARC` - `Automatic Reference Counting` is a mechanism which manages a memory, which is applicable for `reference` type[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219141/4770877). An object is deallocated only when there are 0 references on it.

`Strong reference` - is set by default and it is safe to use this type in a linear relationships(there is no loop)

`Retain cycle` - it is a situation when each of who objects has a strong reference on each other

Break a `Retain cycle`: `weak` and `unowned`. Both of them does not increase an object's retain count by `+1`, and have next differences

`Weak reference` - When a references object is deallocated(is `nil`), `ARC` set a  `weak` reference to `nil` too. That is why `weak` reference is a variable `var`(can not be a constant `let`)[<sup>[var vs let]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219124/4770877) and that is why it is an `optional`

```
weak var delegate: <Type>?
```

**GENERAL**

`unowned` - When a references object is deallocated(is `nil`), the `unowned` **does not** become a `nil` because `ARC` does not set it. That is why `unowned` reference is **non-optional**

**unowned**(by default)

`safe unowned` - uses `runtime safety check` to throw an exception if `unowned` reference was deallocated.

```
Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but object 0x7fa5dad3f0f0 was already deallocated
```

**unowned(unsafe)**

`unowned(unsafe)` operates by `UnsafePointer` that can create a `dangling pointer`. `__unsafe_unretained` from `Objective-C`. It is a kind of direct memory access which `ARC` does not handle. It can produce **unexpected** behaviour, not just some crash. It has better performance

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

[[EXC_BAD_ACCESS]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67471254/4770877)
[[Closure sample]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001166/4770877)