# @property declaration and curly brackets declarion

Tags: ios, objective-c

i know that this is a silly question but what is the difference between this @property declaration and the declaration inside the curly brackets, or i can just also do

> @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *current

list too instead of writting it inside the curly brackets

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{

    NSMutableString *currentList;
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    dataFileHolder *dataCurrent;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listPopulated;
```

Comment: If you declare any object inside curly brackets than that object is used only that class

Comment: so its private when i write this inside the brackets and the @properties are public, is that what u mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare with the `@property` a getter and setter will be auto-generated based on the parameters you set for the property. In this example the setter and getter would be nonatomic, and be saved with a strong reference.

On the other hand, if you define it in curly brackets, only the variable will be created (no getters and setters)

[Here is a more complete explanation than mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702258/difference-between-properties-and-variables-in-ios-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare any object inside curly brackets than that object is used only that class @interface XMLParser : NSObject 
{

```
NSMutableString *currentList;
NSXMLParser *parser;
dataFileHolder *dataCurrent;
```

}

But if you are declaring your object by using @property like this

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listPopulated;

that means you ca use this NSMutableArray in another class also

There is relation between @property and synthesis like getter setter method @property worked as setter and @synthesis as a getter

Comment: You can use instance variables in other classes if you define them as public...

Comment: Also, your comment about property being the setter and synthesize the getter is wrong. Synthesize generates the getter and setter defined by the property. It has been a while now since synthesize is not needed anymore though

Comment: Also, declaring @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listPopulated; does not mean you can use NSMutableArray in another class, but listPopulated (as long as you include the .h)

Comment: @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listPopulated; why i m not able to use this in another class. If i am declaring this in Class A and want to use in B than i am using it like A.listPopulated

Comment: listPopulated can be used in another class (as long as you include the .h). But NSMutableArray is just the type.

Comment: NSMutableArray can always be used in classes, as long as cocoa is imported

Comment: ya i know but saying about that "that means you ca use this NSMutableArray in another class also" mean object of that NSMutableArray is used in another class

Comment: I see, I understood you wrong then, sorry

Comment: ya its my  mistake that i wrote half thing.