# Objective-C instance variable vs @interface variable

Tags: objective-c

i'm new to iOS programming and its difficult to understand the difference about instance variable. I post you two example, could you explain me what is the difference? (only for instance variable that are not IBOutlet).

in .m file

```
@interface MyClass ()
  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
@end
```

in .m file

```
@implementation MyClass
{
   NSString *_aString;
}
```

In both cases i'm on .m file and i'm declaring "instance" variable. But, what is the difference of declaring them in @interface ( .m file ) and in @implementation with {} ?

I have excluded IBOutlet because there are in @interface only (i guess...)

Answer (score 0):

The @interface variable is called a `property` - thus the `@property`.

Check out this source to find out the difference:

[Difference between properties and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702258/difference-between-properties-and-variables-in-ios-header-file)