# @property and @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, properties, synthesis

I'm very new to Objective C.  (Two days now).  When read about `@synthesize`, it seemed to overlap with my understanding `@property` (which I thought I understood) ...    So, some details need to be ironed out in my mind ... it's bugging me.

Please correct me if I'm wrong about differences of `@property` and `@synthesize`:

If you declare a `@property` in your `@interface`, then you're telling the world that users can expect to use standard getters and setters for that property.  Futhermore, ***XCode will make generic getters and setters for you.***  ... BUT, To what degree does *that* happen with the @property declaration?  ( I.E. does that mean "completely" ... like unseen declarations for it in your `@interface`, and also unseen code in your `@interface`?

-Or-

Does `@property` take care of the unseen code declarations in your `@interface` only - whereas `@synthesize` takes care of the unseen code implementation in your `@implementation` section?  )

Comment: Think of it like this if you have a `@property` more than likely you will need the `@synthesize`. This is because yes `@property` is telling the world that a generic `getter` and `setter` are needed but the `@synthesize` is actually creating the `getters` and `setters`, you can override this and create your own `getters` and `setters` if you like as the ones generated will be very basic. Have a watch of the iTunesU `iPad and iPhone Application Development by Paul Hegarty` this is the way I think of it and it hasn't failed yet.

Comment: Thanks so much Popeye ... ITunes U is FANTASTIC!!!  I'm actually on lesson 4 or Paul's 2011 series.  I'm just backing up, reading XCode 4 Learning Objective C along side these series ... still this was not explicitly clear to me.

Answer (score 18):

First, note that the latest version of Xcode does not require @synthesize at all anymore. You can (and should) just omit it. That said, here's what the pieces do.

`@property` is a declaration of accessors. It is just a declaration. There is very little difference between the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSString *something;
```

vs.

```
- (NSString *)something;
- (void)setSomething:(NSString)aSomething;
```

The main difference is that declaring these methods using `@property` lets the compiler automatically generate (synthesize) the implementations for you. There is no requirement that you let the compiler do it for you. You are absolutely free to implement `something` and `setSomething:` by hand, and it is common to do. But, if you don't implement them by hand, the compiler will automatically create an ivar for you called `_something` and create a reasonable implementation for the getter and setter.

In older versions of Xcode, you had to explicitly request the auto-generation using the `@synthesize` keyword. But that is no longer required. Today, the only reason to use `@synthesize` is if you want the ivar to have a non-standard name (never do that).

A key point here is that the methods `something` and `setSomething:` are *just methods*. There is nothing magical about them. They're not special "property methods." They're just methods that by convention access a piece of state. That piece of state is often stored in an ivar, but does not need to be.

To be even more clear: `object.something` does *not* mean "return the ivar named `_something` from `object`." It means "return the result of `[object something]`, whatever that does." It is common for that to return the value of an ivar.

You should declare all of your state (internal and external) using `@property` declarations, and you should avoid directly declaring ivars. You should also always access your properties via their accessors (`self.something`), except in the `init` and `dealloc` methods. In `init` and `dealloc`, you should directly use the ivar (`_something`).

Comment: Rob,  Thanks so much for your time & response.   Watching iOS videos on iTunes U from last year(2011) ... and trying to keep up with changes going on in XCode make for some confusion at times.  Listening carefully to the instructor, and even making test with simple code ... heck, even reading XCode documentation didn't fully clear up that @synthesis was not necessary!   Helpful confirmation like yours adds to confidence that I didn't learn something wrong ... as I continue along.   :-)   Now ... if someone has some outside link where I can start thinking properly about MVC - that'd be great!!

Comment: Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14. Then here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: 'You should declare all of your state (internal and external) using @property declarations, and you should avoid directly declaring ivars' are there any times when you should not do this?

Comment: The most common case is if you override both the getter and setter, but still need an ivar. You need to declare the ivar then by hand, but it doesn't change access. A rare case I occasionally face is when I have an ivar that is *always* accessed as a raw memory pointer (a malloc'ed buffer for instance), so there is no use for accessors. See my private ivars in https://github.com/rnapier/richtext-coretext/blob/master/PinchText/Classes/PinchTextLayer.m for an example. But these are rare cases. You should use properties unless there is a compelling reason you cannot.

Comment: So can I say that the compiler reads the @ property declaration the generate @ synthesize, @ synthesize generates the getter and the setter?

Answer (score 7):

`@property` declares a property on your class with whatever atomicity and setter semantics you provide.

With Xcode 4.4, autosynthesis is available wherein you are provided with a backing ivar from your property without declaring it in `@synthesize`.  This ivar has the form of `_propertyName` where your property name is `propertyName`.

Comment: This has hit the nail on the head, short sweet and simple. +1

Comment: Yes ... I knew you could "back your property var" with a different ivar ( which should be used by your class, and especially with the getters and setters. ) ...  Thanks so very much for your response ... I've overwhelmed with the speed of helpful replies coming in ... (This is my first post here after joining only minutes ago )!     - Thanks for taking to time to make this post Alan!

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C @property and @synthesize**

**`@property`**

- generates get/set method
- today(from Xcode v4.4 with the LLVM v4.0) `@property` additionally uses `@synthesize` inside

  - @synthesize propertyName = _propertyName

**`@synthesize`**:

- generates a new iVar or link with existing iVar
- generates an implementation of the get/set method with an appropriate iVar

[[Case when @synthesize can be used]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233088/4770877)

`@property`

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property NSString *foo;
@end

//generated code
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
- (NSString *)foo;
- (void)setFoo:(NSString)newFoo;
@end
```

`@synthesize` pattern

```
@synthesize <property_name> = <variable_name>;

//Using
//1. Specify a variable. New variable(variableName) will be generated/linked with existing
@synthesize propertyName = variableName

//if variableName is not exist it generates: 
//NSString *variableName;

//read access
NSString *temp = variableName;

//2. Default. New variable(propertyName - the same name as a property) will be generated/linked with existing
@synthesize propertyName
//is the same as
//@synthesize propertyName = propertyName

//if propertyName is not exist it generates:  
//NSString *propertyName;

//read access
NSString *temp = propertyName;

//if you specify not-existing <property_name>  you  get
//Property implementation must have its declaration in interface '<class_name>' or one of its extensions
```

previously you had to use next syntax:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    //1. declare variable
    NSString *_foo;
}
//2. create property
@property NSString *foo;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
//3. link property and iVar
@synthesize foo = _foo;
@end
```

But today you can use next syntax

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
//1. create property
@property NSString *foo;
@end
```

Next, **the same code**, will be generated for both cases

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    //variable
    NSString *_foo; 
}

//getter/setter
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)newFoo;
- (NSString *)foo;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)newFoo
{
    _foo = newFoo;
}
- (NSString *)foo
{
    return _foo;
}
@end
```