# Do I need to include @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

I created a `@property` by right-clicking and dragging from `ViewController.xib` into `ViewController.h`, but `@synthesize` is not being automatically created in `ViewController.m`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730244/property-and-synthesize) said that `@synthesize` is no longer necessary, but I'm wondering if auto-complete needs `@synthesize` for it to work correctly.

Q: Do I need to include `@synthesize`?

Answer (score 10):

In a word, no. Xcode 4.5 is fully aware of the fact that `@synthesize` is no longer required. You're good to go without!

Comment: @Phillip If my answer was sufficient for your needs, could you please accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using ARC @synthesize auto appears. outside ARC you have to add it. Adrian

Comment: It's a compiler addition, it's unrelated to ARC. You don't need to specify @synthesize in retain/release code either in Xcode 4.5

Comment: You do if your code is supposed to work with GCC or the LLVM+GCC frontend, or if it may be compiled with an older SDK.

Comment: Note, though, that Apple has officially deprecated the use of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are good to go but make sure you specify it like this:
self.textInput.text=@"Hello world"
Without the self it is not recognized.