# iOS 7 Dev - @synthesize not auto creating ivars

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, synthesize

I'm currently working with the latest version of Xcode (v5.0.2) and my app has a deployment target of iOS 7.0.

My problem is that no matter in what class, i can set a property in the header

ex: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;`

in the implementation file, I can synthesize it just fine

ex: `@synthesize firstName;`

My problem is that I cannot use `_firstName` in the code. I have used the automatic ivars in other projects just fine (the property name   preceded with the underscore).

Xcode complains and tells me to change it to the name of the property without the underscore. I don't understand why this project isn't creating the ivars with the underscore for me automatically. I know that in older versions of Objective-C, you had to do this yourself but you don't for iOS 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just skip the `@synthesize` completely, and it will create underscored ivars. If you do `@synthesize` without specifying the variable name (`@synthesize firstName = _firstName;`), it will create variables without underscores.

Answer (score 3):

`@synthesize` create an ivar for your property

**In this line**

`@synthsize firstName = otherName;`

where `firstName` is your property name while `otherName` is your ivar name

**In your line**

`@synthesize firstName;` === `@synthesize firstName = firstName;`

So The property and ivar are the same which is `firstName`

**If you didn't write any `@synthesize`**

then the compiler will put

`@synthesize firstName = _firstName;`

In which `firstName` is the property name and `_firstName` is the ivar name

Answer (score 2):

Skip the `@synthesize` and it will be fine in your case. Since you use a new XCode version you do not really need this in this case. Please take a look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016117/do-i-need-to-include-synthesize) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730244/property-and-synthesize)).

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother using the @synthesize (unless it's an NSManagedObject subclass). But, it's rare that you should use the direct ivar anyway. Outside of your init methods you should always use self.firstName.

Comment: I'd say "Outside of init, dealloc, and getter/setter methods".