# confused about classes and objects iVar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@property and @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730244/property-and-synthesize)

What does it mean when a class has a property, but has no variable for it? 
rather I see things like:

```
@interface myClass : someClass

    @property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton* button;

@end
```

and in the implementation:

```
@synthesize button = _button;
```

So who is `_button`?

What does the `@synthesize` do when declared like this?
Does this mean that the class now has a private var called `_button`? Can I treat `_button` as a private var of the class?

Comment: iVar is autogenerated, in XCode 4.4 and higher you don't need to write @synthesize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the class now has a private var called _button? Can I treat _button as a private var of the class?

Yes, this is a new feature of the Clang compiler - it automatically creates instance variables for properties, and the ivar has `@private` access level and has the `_namwOfProperty` if the name of the property is `nameOfProperty`.

Comment: It's even more restricted than `@private`: a synthesized ivar is only visible in the file where the synthesize directive is located.

Comment: @JoshCaswell apart from categories, isn't that the same as `@private`?

Comment: Right, an `@private` ivar is available inside of a category on the class, but a synthesized variable isn't.