# Usage of @Dynamic

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

please help me to know why we are using `@property` and `@synthesis`? Where we need to use `@dynamic`?
Thank you.

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@property` is a declaration of `accessors`. It is just a declaration. There is very little difference between these.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730244/property-and-synthesize)

Answer (score 1):

Properties

When we wrote the accessor methods for caption and author earlier, you might have noticed that the code is straightforward, and could probably be generalized.

Properties are a feature in Objective-C that allow us to automatically generate accessors, and also have some other side benefits. Let's convert the Photo class to use properties.

Here's what it looked like before:
    #import

```
@interface Photo : NSObject {
   NSString* caption;
   NSString* photographer;
}
- (NSString*) caption;
- (NSString*) photographer;

- (void) setCaption: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setPhotographer: (NSString*)input;

@end
```

Here's what it looks like once converted to properties:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Photo : NSObject {
    NSString* caption;
    NSString* photographer;
}
@property (retain) NSString* caption;
@property (retain) NSString* photographer;

@end
```

The @property is an Objective-C directive which declares the property. The "retain" in the parenthesis specifies that the setter should retain the input value, and the rest of the line simply specifies the type and the name of the property.

Now let's take a look at the implementation of the class:

```
#import "Photo.h"

@implementation Photo

@synthesize caption;
@synthesize photographer;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [caption release];
   [photographer release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The @synthesize directive automatically generates the setters and getters for us, so all we have to implement for this class is the dealloc method.

@synthesize will generate getter and setter methods for your property. @dynamic just tells the compiler that the getter and setter methods are implemented not by the class itself but somewhere else

Comment: yah. these all things i know. where we should use this? and where we dnt need?

Answer (score 0):

@property and @synthesis work together, it helps you define setter and getter automatically. In xcode 4.5, @synthesis is not required, compiler auto add it.